# FULLTEXT index matching problems with CodeIgniter Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to create a fulltext search indexing based on CodeIgniter query builder and I got weird result which is said :

```
Error Number: 1191</p><p>Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list</p><p>SELECT *
FROM `posts`
LEFT JOIN `post_reg_sub_cat` ON `post_reg_sub_cat`.`id`=`posts`.`regional`
LEFT JOIN `post_reg_cat` ON `post_reg_cat`.`id_reg_cat`=`post_reg_sub_cat`.`id_reg_cat`
WHERE `id_post` != '129'
AND `post_reg_cat`.`reg_cat` = 'lampung'
AND MATCH (title) AGAINST("saya-punya-3-pertanyaan-untuk-brigita-manohara")
 LIMIT 5</p><p>Filename: models/M_api.php</p><p>Line Number: 347
```

However, I do some research to run this query manually inside phpMyAdmin web client, so I just copy exactly the query code up there and the result works fine.

Here is my model

```
function getRegRelasilNews($id, $slug, $limit) {
        $ur = base_url();
        $parse = parse_url($ur);
        $host = explode('.', $parse['host']);

        $subdomain = $host[0];

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->join('post_reg_sub_cat', 'post_reg_sub_cat.id=posts.regional','left');
        $this->db->join('post_reg_cat', 'post_reg_cat.id_reg_cat=post_reg_sub_cat.id_reg_cat','left');
        $this->db->where('id_post !=', $id);
        $this->db->where('post_reg_cat.reg_cat', $subdomain);
        $this->db->where('MATCH (title) AGAINST("'.$slug.'")' , NULl);
        $this->db->limit($limit);
        return $this->db->get($this->table)->result();
    }
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Should be done like this

Fist make sure that you have added column title to FULLTEXT index in Phpmyadmin or you can use the query below

```
ALTER TABLE `Table_name` ADD FULLTEXT (`title`)
```

Then make some changes in your query after select your first table syntax should be like this

```
 $this->db->from('first_table_name');
```

Then in where match Against should be use like Below

```
$this->db->where('MATCH (table_name.title) AGAINST("'.$slug.'")');
```

use table_name.column name for each column because you are using joins and it will give a crash if there will same name columns in other tables.

Comment: It would be sensible to avoid the SQL injection at the end - the question author may not know about this security vulnerability, and this sort of thing is a good opportunity to teach them about parameter binding.

Comment: Sorry for late reply but your code it work. I just forgot to accepted it.